# Excel 2007 VBA: delete row if cell value is between 600 and 699

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling with this question for a while.  I am trying to write the VBA code to finish this multi-worksheet macro and I'll say thank you in advance for your time & knowledge.  I sincerely appreciate it.

I have a sheet of roughly 10 columns, 4,000 rows.  The goal is to search column "E" for values between 600 and 699, and delete any row that has column E with a value between 600 and 699.

Right now I'm using this line to delete a row containing "602":

```
Dim FoundCell As Range
Set FoundCell = Worksheets("StoreEmployeeImport").Range("E:E").Find(what:=602)
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
    Set FoundCell = Worksheets("StoreEmployeeImport").Range("E:E").FindNext
Loop
```

Is there a way to do this for all values between 600 and 650?  The 'quick and dirty way" is to write this loop for all fifty possible values between 600 and 650 BUT I know there is a better way.  Probably much simpler.

THANKS!

Comment: Thank you- I'll try both of these and report back.  This will make my life much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handle it

```
'Get the last row, 65000th row and column E
finalRow=cells(65000,5).end(xlup).row
'Loop through data backwards
for i = finalRow to 1 step -1
  'Do your check
  if cells(i,5) > 600 and cells(i,5) < 650 then
    'Delete the row if criteria met
    cells(i,1).entirerow.delete
  end if
next i
```

Comment: this works perfectly, I really appreciate the help.  I typed it in exactly as you have it and it just WORKED.  Love it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "E").Value
        If v > 599 And v < 700 Then
            Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution should work faster than mine because it turns screen updating off while it runs and it dimensions the variables.